# How do I make a Bootstrap Icon appear?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am new to Bootstrap and I'm building a login screen for an app. I want to use the the MDBIcons for google, twitter and facebook. I followed the documentaion here https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/react/components/buttons/

However, when I view my webpage I can't see the icons. I only a small button in the color of the brand. My code for the google icon button looks like this

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import {  MDBIcon,  MDBBtn } from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
 
const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <>

      <MDBBtn
              className="m-1"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "#dd4b39" }}
              href="#"
            >
              <MDBIcon fab icon="google" />
            </MDBBtn>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: photo of button]

The picture above is what I see, there is no Google logo in the button. I am using React and running 'npm start' to view my webpage on chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the following should work:
import { MDBBtn, MDBIcon } from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
<MDBBtn className='m-1' style={{ backgroundColor: '#dd4b39' }} href='#'>                  <MDBIcon fab icon='google' />
</MDBBtn>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add style in the public/index.html file? Info about it is here. [React MDB Installation Guide](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/react/getting-started/installation/#section-npm).

I mean this:

```
link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

If not, try adding this into your **index.html** file's "head" section.